# .env variable returns undefined in React JS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powershell, environment-variables, dotenv

I am working on this react app and thinking of adding some environment variables inside, this is what I've done:

1. installed the latest version of react-scripts
2. added .env file on the root folder (the same location where node_modules folder is)
3. added REACT_APP_OTHER_OTHER_THING=asdfas just to test the variable

> ```
> REACT_APP_OTHER_OTHER_THING=asdfas
> ```

4. open index.js and console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_OTHER_OTHER_THING) inside to see the output

> ```
> import React from 'react';
> import Reactdom from 'react-dom';
> import App from './App';
>
> console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_OTHER_OTHER_THING, 'DOTENV')
>
> Reactdom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("app"))
> ```

then I rebuilt the app and started the app to see the result
but then it gives out undefined as the output for process.env.REACT_APP_OTHER_OTHER_THING. I then tried to print process.env.NODE_ENV (which is working and prints "development" as output).

note: I have also tried to add temporary variable as the docs said in https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables >> rebuilt the server and run ***($env:REACT_APP_OTHER_OTHER_THING= "abcdef") -and (npm start)*** << due to me running it on powershell which still gives undefined as output.

is there anything I can do on this?
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, the problem I'm having seemed to be from the webpack I made in my React App,

I tried to follow the instruction from this [article](https://medium.com/@trekinbami/using-environment-variables-in-react-6b0a99d83cf5) and it's working well!

after configuring my webpack, I rebuilt it, restart the server, and it works!

edit: for my solution, I added:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
    return prev; }, {});
```

at the top of webpack.common.js

and also added

```
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys), //this line
    ]
```

in the module.exports
in the plugin. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: It would be great to add the related portion of article just in case the url may become invalid some day

Comment: I only restarted my server and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

**Ensure it has correct directory tree**

#### D:\your-react-project \ .env

- Here it maybe **your-react-project \ .env.development**

**It should be in the path of where default README.md placed**

Answer (score 1):

Can't comment, so i will post an answer, sorry.

Are you sure about `($REACT_APP_OTHER_OTHER_THING= "abcdef") -and (npm start)`, because docs says `($env:REACT_APP_NOT_SECRET_CODE = "abcdef") -and (npm start)`

I just added new env var, and it gave me undefined, but after server restart it worked just fine. Can you try to restart server, but add env variable not in terminal, but inside `.env` file?

UPD1:
just so you know, `NODE_ENV` is set by `npm start` or `npm run build` commands, they set to `development` or `production`, respectively.

As docs says:

> You cannot override NODE_ENV manually. This prevents developers from accidentally deploying a slow development build to production.

Comment: my bad, I retyped them in the question, not copy it from the one I typed on my command prompt, thank you for the revision - I'm sorry, my first time posting question here :(

Comment: for the NODE_ENV, I know the value would be "development", I printed it out to see if the process.env is actually working. the problem I'm seeing is that process.env.NODE_ENV is working just as said in the docs, but not about the variables I made in .env file

Comment: @JustinusAmadiaWijaya can you share your .env file?

Comment: my .env file only consists of a line written --> REACT_APP_OTHER_OTHER_THING=asdsafas

Answer (score 1):

Actually problem with VS Code Editor

Create a .env file using the terminal in the project root directory

```
touch .env
```

and then it is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

Please check these things first:

1. the variable must be prefixed with REACT_APP_
   eg: REACT_APP_WEBSITE_NAME=hello
2. You need to restart the server to reflect the changes.
3. Make sure you have the .env file in your root folder(same place where you have your package.json) and NOT in your src folder.

Comment: This is a good point, @Ferdaus, it would be a better answer if you provided the reference and why: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/
"You must create custom environment variables beginning with REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with the same issue. I double-checked everything was connected correctly then killed my server in the terminal after started it back up & it worked fine.

Answer (score -3):

Other causes of undefined environment variables on a much simpler level than the op's Webpack configuration question include:

- Leaving out process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL and just writing REACT_APP_SERVER_URL in your code
- Forgetting to name the environment variable with REACT_APP as the first part of the string